# What is the correct way to handle exceptions in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out what is the best way to handle exceptions in a python script.

Let's say I have a script that defines several functions. Those functions deal with file manipulation operations and of course things could go wrong and all sorts of exceptions may be raised, such as `FileNotFoundError`, `FileExistsError`, etc. I assume that for each function, I have a known list of exceptions that may be raised, according to the operations I define for that function.

So let's say I have a script looking something like:

```
def foo():
 # let's say foo can raise "FileExistsError" and "FileNotFoundError"


def bar():
  # let's say bar can raise "PermissionError"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  .. some code
  foo()
  bar()
```

My goals with regards to exception handling are:

- The user should receive the most clear report possible about the failure, with the least exposure to technical details. So I want to process the exceptions raised before displaying them to the user
- The code should, of course, remain as readable and concise as possible
- All the exceptions are caught and handled

The question is, what is the best way to achieve this.
What I was thinking is something like:

```
def foo():
    try:
        # this will raise a FileNotFoundError
        shutil.copy("non_existing_file", "new_file")
    except:
        raise 

def bar():
    try:
        # this will raise a PermissionError
        shutil.copy("error-handling.py", "C:\\Windows\\System\\script.py")
    except:
        raise


try:
    foo()
    bar()
except (OSError, FileNotFoundError, PermissionError) as err:
    print(err)
```

My wonders are:

- Is there a point in handling the exceptions in the functions, if I'm handling them in the main script?
- Maybe I should define a new type of exception class, and for each function catch the exceptions that may be raised, and raise my user-defined exception with a formatted string?

Comment: One very good rule I once heard is "never catch an exception you aren't prepared to handle".  What that means is that, in many cases, the best plan is NOT to catch the exception, and let the system handle it.  If your script fails with a PermissionError, doesn't that tell the user all they need to know?  What can you possibly add to that?

Comment: All Python file exceptions are subclasses of `OSError`, no need to list those subclasses when you handle the base class. If you have a _GUI application_ handle errors accordingly, catch them and produce clear error messages at the point where you handled the user interaction. Your `try:...except: raise` is pointless, you don't need those, you are just catching and re-throwing. Remove those.

Comment: You should only ever handle exceptions you expect and need to handle for the application to work correctly. E.g. if you run into an `AttributeError` when you don't expect one, that's probably a bug. But if your code is _designed_ to try to access an attribute that may not exist, and you can handle that case (perhaps by creating the missing attribute), then use an exception handler.

Comment: There's no point to any of the exception handling you're currently doing, as you didn't add any unique behavior to what would happen otherwise.

Comment: @TimRoberts you could replace the exception with one that has a friendlier string for example.  But this code isn't even attempting that.

Answer (score 1):

What I personally like to do is to use wrappers to catch errors.
Here is an example of how you could implement it.

```
def decorator_func(*errors):
    def inner(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except errors as e:
                print(traceback.format_exc())  
# You should add here behaviour you want to achieve. 
# trackback - you need to import this module but it will allow you to print some usefull info.
# But it is up to you what info you want to pass to user.
        return wrapper
    return inner
```

Then you can use it when defining methods:

```
@decorator_func(Exception)  # replace Exception with the exception you expect
def foo(): pass

@decorator_func(KeyError, ValueError)  # You can pass more than one exception
def bar(): pass
```

Answer (score 1):

[@Relandom's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68060362/9997212) is great. Answering your second question, you can do something like that to provide a custom message for each error type using the same idea:

```py
def handle(error, msg):
    def _(func):
        def __(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except error as e:
                print(msg)
            
        return __    
    return _

@handle(Exception, "Unknown error.")
@handle(TypeError, "You must pass a numeric value.")
@handle(ZeroDivisionError, "You must not pass zero.")
def func(value):
    value /= value    
    return 1 + value
    
print(func(1))
# Output:
# 2

print(func(0))
# Output:
# You must not pass zero.
# None

print(func("a"))
# Output:
# You must pass a numeric value.
# None
```

Note that, by using the above approach:

- If you handle `Exception`, it must be the top-most decorator.
- Generally, if you must handle the exceptions A and B, where B is a subclass of A (for example, handling `OSError` and `FileNotFoundError`), the A decorator must be on the top of the B decorator.
- You can't provide two different messages for the same error type (e.g. if your code tries to open two different files, you can't define a message for `FileNotFoundError` when the first file can't be found and another message for `FileNotFoundError` when the second file can't be found).

Answer (score 0):

If you know what exceptions can be raised you can directly check them in the function and get the context like so:

```
def foo():
    try:
        # this will raise a FileNotFoundError
        shutil.copy("non_existing_file", "new_file")
    except FileNotFoundError as err:
        args = err.args # this gets all the exception arguments
        reason = err.__str__() # this converts the message given into a string

        ### WRITE YOUR HANDLING CODE HERE ###

        raise FileNotFoundError(EXPLANATION) from err # this raises the final exception from the previous one

    except Exception as err: # this will be called if the previous one(s) isn't/aren't called
       args = err.args # this gets all the exception arguments
        reason = err.__str__() # this converts the message given into a string

       ### WRITE YOUR HANDLING CODE HERE ###

       raise EXCEPTIONTYPE(EXPLANATION) from err # this raises the final exception from the previous one

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo()
```

Here *EXCEPTIONTYPE* can be replaced by the name of the exception you want to raise after handling the error and *EXPLANATION* can be replaced by what you want to tell the user in the explanation part, i.e. after "Exception: "